# Powershell: Retrieve xml data from column in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

Following [this tutorial](http://sqlmag.com/site-files/sqlmag.com/files/archive/sqlmag.com/content/content/100458/listing11.txt) I tried to use PowerShell to retrieve xml data from SQL Server, but I only get one element back.

Here is a query to show the actual data:

[image]

But running this script I only get one element back:

```
$SQLServer = 'MYSERVER,1433'
$SQLDBName = "test"
$Query = 
@'
USE test

SELECT EventLogXML FROM ForwardedEvents

'@
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlConnection.open()    
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$xr = $SqlCmd.ExecuteXmlReader()
$xd = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDataDocument
$xd.Load($xr)
$xr.Close()
$SQLConnection.Close()
$xd
```

`$xd` only has one element. What am I doing wrong?

---edit
I can confirm its only one xml doc by doing $xd.outerxml which reveals the complete doc. It is only one of the thousand or so event xml docs I'm storing in the EventLogXML column.

Comment: Naturally, you'd have one document per row. And since you creating one document only, it's not surprising that you get only information from a single row in it. Did you expect all these separate xmls from all the rows to be combined somehow? If so, how?

Comment: Hmm, something fundamental I'm missing here. I thought $xd was supposed be an object containing all the rows. Its not? I wanted to return an array of all the xml objects in the column that I could loop through. I have never worked with sql like this before so I think I'm misunderstanding what the script is actually doing.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my bad. I misread `XmlDataDocument` as `XmlDocument`. Please disregard my earlier comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that XmlDataDocument is mainly for returning a single xml. Basically if you do in sql `select * from bla for xml, auto` you then can read it with the `ExecuteXmlReader` and `XmlDataDocument`. This is not what you want.

Modifying the example you linked to your needs we'll get somethign like:

```
$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = "Server=.; Database=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=true"
$con.open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Instructions FROM Production.ProductModel WHERE Instructions is not null"
$cmd.Connection = $con

$as = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$as.SelectCommand = $cmd
$as.Fill($ds);

$xmlDocs = $ds.Tables[0] | %{ [xml]$_.Instructions }
```

Now xmlDocs will contain a list of xml documents, one document per row.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do. The only reason I was using XmlDataDocument was because I was getting a weird error when assigning the complete "SELECT * FROM TABLE" query to a single variable. My question should have explained this was my initial issue. Well I just tried using a "new" variable to store the dataset and it worked, oops. All of this because I accidentally cast the variable I was using to some weird type before I tried using it to store the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell wraps XML stuff into handy little objects, which you can explore using `.Property` syntax.  If you just look at `$xd`, powershell by default will only show you the root node.

I don't know the structure of your XML column, but if the root node is called `MyRoot`, followed by common subnodes called `MySub`, try something like this:

```
$xd.MyRoot.MySub
```

This is just as the linked example shows the need to use `$xd.root.Location`

**Edit**

Ok so that is not the problem.  Looks like it is by-design to return back only the first row when calling `ExecuteXmlReader` with a normal `select` statement (doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css)):

> if more than one row is returned, the ExecuteXmlReader method attaches
>   the XmlReader to the value on the first row, and discards the rest of
>   the result set

From some basic searching around, [this blog post](http://smeans.com/2008/03/12/fun-with-sqlcommandexecutexmlreader/) seems to explain the issue the best, and provides a workaround.  See also [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/923768/1068075.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, but that's not it. It really is only one xml doc. I can confirm this by doing $xd.outerxml which reveals the complete element. I'll add this info as an edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I may be out to lunch, but couldn't it be because you are declaring the database as $SQLDBName and then trying to connect to $Database in your connectionstring?

Comment: Oh noes! didn't even notice that. I'll correct this tomorrow at work and test.